# Aggregation Builders in MongoDB with Kotlin :: Unrecognized expression for a simple addField

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, aggregation-framework

I am using the mongodb kotlin-sync:4.11.0 driver and connecting to a db versioned on 4.4.
In my Aggregation pipeline built in compass I have a simple $addField step that looks like this:

```json
{
  newField: {
    $filter: {
      input: "$existingField",
      as: "ent",
      cond: {
        $eq: ["$$ent.primary", true],
      },
    },
  },
}
```

It correctly adds a new array field on when it finds an array member of 'existingField' whoes 'primary' field exists and is set to True.

The same aggregation stage in Kotlin via the builders is not – I can't seem to get the format right? The docs at [MongoDB kotlin Docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/kotlin/coroutine/current/fundamentals/builders/aggregates/#addfields) is no help at all.

Looking at the below, what am I missing here?

```kotlin
fun onlyArrayMemberPrimaryValuesTrue(): Bson = Aggregates.set(
    Field("newField", Filters.elemMatch("existingField",
        Filters.eq("primary", true))
    )
)
```

A simple version works fine, any attempts at a more complex expression fails.

```kotlin
val basic: Bson = set(Field("some.new.field", "\$some.existing.field"))     // ✅
```

@prasad_ tried now:

```kotlin
fun addFieldIssueExampleTry(): Bson {
    val ent = current().getArray<MqlDocument>("existingField").first()
    return Aggregates.addFields(
        Field("newField", ent)
    )
}
```

Errors : "Invalid $addFields :: caused by :: Unrecognized expression '$getField'", "code": 168, "codeName": "InvalidPipelineOperator".

Comment: You may want to look at the Aggregation Operators - `$filter` - usage in: [Array Operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/kotlin/coroutine/current/fundamentals/aggregation-expression-operations/)

Comment: @prasad_ nice kick in the right direction I think, but that also knocks off the same error : "Invalid $addFields :: caused by :: Unrecognized expression '$getField'", "code": 168, "codeName": "InvalidPipelineOperator"...

Comment: Looking at that error, it is saying `Unrecognized expression '$getField'` Which is true, my DB is at v4.4 and the $getField is new in 5.0 Why is the driver not using 4.4 available api? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/getField/
The compatibility for the driver is listed as working on 4.4 https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/kotlin/coroutine/current/compatibility/